# I'm a monster in the water. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm tall, yet my arms are short.
>   
>   I move above the water, and it is based on a theory. 
>   
>   I benefit from it, while others don't.
>   
>   I was made, along with brothers, kept as a secret.
>   
>   When I was found, people nicknamed me with fear.

What am I?

Comment: You are obviously a tall psychic person with short arms.

Comment: Well, nice try. However, what I have in mind is far away from that. I usually make the solution describe itself as "human being." Maybe a bit more clue can make it more reasonable.

Comment: Riddle edited. I admit that inital one is not good enough. Happy puzzling!

Comment: Ok, the edit rules out my half-written answer "*submarine*".

Comment: Is the "thing" floating on water or above water (in air)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor What a nice try! Submarine makes sense to the riddle! But I would prefer to emphasise that the second line is how the "thing" move, maybe you take the title into consideration?

Comment: Is this "thing" fictional or real?

Comment: @smriti This thing is real, and it has made just a few decades ago.

Comment: "move ... based on theory" could refer to a theory for "change" or scientific theory, for instance germ theory - which would lead me to waterborne diseases.. and then it just gets dark.

Comment: Well, it is a scientific theory, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are

> The [Caspian Sea Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_Sea_Monster) a ground effect vehicle (ekranoplan) which is a craft that flies, but stays close to the surface.

I'm tall, yet my arms are short.

> It's height about 21.8 m and wingspan 37.6 m

I move above the water, and it is based on a theory. I benefit from it, while others don't.

> Flying only at an altitude of 5-10 m usually above water (needs a flat surface below) it benefited from the [ground effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_(aerodynamics)) which is not experienced at higher altitudes.

I was made, with brothers, kept as a secret. When I was found, people nicknamed me with fear.

> It was spotted flying above the Caspian sea by photographs from satellites which showed a strange aircraft carrying letters "KM" on its fuselage. CIA disambiguated it as "Kaspian Monster", while it actually meant "Korabl maket" – "prototype ship" in Russian. It flew from 1966 until it crashed in 1980.
>  
> In recent years a large number of different GEV types have been developed for both civilian and military use. However, these craft have yet to enter widespread use - [ground effect vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_vehicle)

Comment: That's it! I thought it would be closed again. Well, there is another fact for the third line: the Russian ekranoplan was build for different purpose, like military transport or anti-ship attack mission.

Comment: Nice puzzle - I saw a documentary on it once - and yes I see others not benefiting from the military side now!  These are educational and interesting!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! A fun fact behind the puzzle: I had a presentation for this 3 days ago, and I had been collected the reference for the past 3 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could be:

> the "Fat Man", a nuke bomb delivered in Japan in a plane over the Pacific Ocean (a lot of water below him!).
>
> It was based on the atomic theorym and it has at least 2 brothers (2 other nukes) all known with code names (nicknames!) "Little Boy" and "The Gadget". 
>
> These nukes were named with fear and had 3 meters length.

Comment: Well, I admit that is a nice try! It is reasonable for most line of the riddle, yet the second line said the "thing" is based on a theory to move, rather than explode.